# Alfresco authenticate with LDAP with sha stored password

Tags: java, ldap, alfresco

I am new in Alfresco.
My mission is to configure Alfresco with a LDAP server.

after same googling I found the way to configure the ldap server and the synchro of the users.

The problem is that my ldap server store the password with the SHA encryption method.

I saw this property in the documentation

```
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication
```

But it's looks like this property support just md5 encryption.

Did you have any experience like this one?

Thanks 
Marco

Comment: Did you try following the Alfresco documentation? How far did you get? What problems did you hit? (Alfresco ought to work just fine with LDAP no matter what format your LDAP server stores its passwords in)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this webpage could be useful: http://www.ochounos.com/#blog/6

Best regards.

Comment: The above link is dead, as of 11-11-2017.  This is why it's better to post the content along with links, instead of not just the link.  :-(